# appending results to a list

Tags: r, append, lapply, quantmod, yahoo-finance

I have the following code that successfully calculates the beta, via the CAPM, for a list of stocks through the use of lapply. However, I want to append the regression coefficients (beta) to a separate list (or extract them from the capm list) after each stock is run through the model. My problem is that the append does not work inside my lapply function. I am hoping that the datalist list would have the coefficients.

```
library(qmao)
library(broom)

startDate = as.Date("2013-10-01") #Specify what date to get the prices from
endDate = as.Date("2016-09-30")

symbols <- c('AAPL','AMZN')
data.env <- new.env()
getSymbols(symbols, env = data.env ,from= startDate ,to= endDate)
pf <- PF(symbols,env = data.env,silent=TRUE) # consolidated xts-object
pfMth <- pf[endpoints(pf,on='months'),]   # get monthly endpoints
pfMthRets <- ROC(pfMth,type='discrete')  
pfMthRets <- na.omit(pfMthRets)

tail(pfMthRets)
plot(pfMthRets$AAPL)

getSymbols("^gspc",from = startDate, to = endDate)
GSPC_Adjusted = GSPC$GSPC.Adjusted
GSPC.mrtn <- monthlyReturn(GSPC$GSPC.Adjusted)
GSPC.mrtn <- GSPC.mrtn [-1,]
names(GSPC.mrtn)[1] <- "SP"

datalist = list()
lapply(symbols, function(symbols) {
input <- as.formula(paste("pfMthRets$",symbols, "~ GSPC.mrtn$SP" ))
capm <- lm( input)
datalist <- append(datalist, coefficients(capm))
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
res <- lapply(symbols, function(symbols) {
    input <- as.formula(paste("pfMthRets$",symbols, "~ GSPC.mrtn$SP" ))
    capm <- lm( input)
    coefficients(capm)
})

res2 <- do.call(rbind, res)

# > res2
# (Intercept) GSPC.mrtn$SP
# [1,] 0.006102159     1.523730
# [2,] 0.017761587     1.509065
```

Your problem arises because inside `lapply` your `datalist` does not append the results as you cycle through the symbols (in each call of your function, `datalist` is an empty list).  You want to "combine" (`rbind`) the results of the output of `lapply` operations.  A common way to do it is with `do.call`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I had gone around and around with the do.call function outside of the loop but could not get it to work. The key was the coefficients(capm) line. A great learning experience.